# Controlling multiple Screens using IR

Tags: arduino-uno, nodemcu, ir

I'm a software Engineer, and recently I’ve been working on a new Software
Part of this Software is to be able to turn off and on multiple TV screens using timers in the software 
First idea came to my mind is using relays with Arduino and connecting in to computer using Bluetooth chip but not all screens turns on once the power cable is plugged in
So, I tried IR CIRCUIT using NODEMCU and IR LEDS. And it worked but not perfectly,
The way I did this is by sending a combination of IR codes to screen to make a sleep timer so it will turn off the screen after some time.
But there was a delay when sending IR codes, and sometimes the code won’t be sent 
This is the circuit I used (in addition to more  IR LEDS)
[image]
I just want to know why the codes are not sent every time 
And if there is any better way to control the screens from computer?

Comment: Can you show us the code you have written?

Comment: There are ready-made items for this purpose, such as the iTach Flex with (triple) IR emitter. You may consider using something off-the-shelf to save time and to avoid messing around/frustration.